# Trouble transferring Mail folders to a new Mac

Tags: mail.app

I just bought a new Mac.

I want to transfer everything in my Mail install from my previous Mac to this new one. This includes all of the folders that I created "on my Mac"—meaning the contents are stored on the hard drive rather than on the IMAP server.

I've tried copying everything from the ~/Library/Mail/ folder as well as the Mail-related items in ~/Library/Preferences/, but when I launch Mail on the new Mac those 'local' folders aren't there.

I suppose I could manually export them from the old Mac and import them to the new Mac, but that seems incredibly laborious and unnecessary.

Any ideas? This is stumping me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try: File -> Import Mailboxes

Then point it to the mailboxes you copied over (in `~/Library/Mail/V4`).

Comment: Sorry where are those? In the V4 folder?

Comment: Yes, the ~/Library/Mail/ folders